# Python - Django BASE_DIR is not populating completely

Tags: python, django

I am facing a strange issue with django BASE_DIR . My codebase base directory is apisetup. When i am using BASE_DIR for linking css and js files with the help of "static". But those are not working in production. When i see console , it is giving 404 errors for css and js files. the base directory is not reflecting completely. LAST LETTER is missing in the base path.

eg : `*****.com/**apisetu**/static/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js` , but it should be **`apisetup`**

##### settings.py file

```py
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

In local it is working fine but creating issue in hosting server. Please help me out to understand the issue and resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL settings. `linking css and js files with the help of "static"` please show example of such linting. Also take into account that on prod you should not serve static files by Django, you should configure Nginx or other webserver for such work. If Nginx/Apache is involved please show its' config. Also it might be helpful if you tag your deployment target platform if Azure or something like that is used.

Comment: Grep your repository for `\bapisetu\b`. I suspect you'll find a reason somewhere there.